# How can I create a Dataframe with indexs of different Period

Tags: pandas, numpy, dataframe, time-series, timespan

I have a Dataframe, each row represent a record produced by pbs. Now I want the know the running cores in each time period(30 minite).
The first 4 rows of my table:

```
datetime    walltime    ncores
2019-07-18 11:18:27 2:05:10     2
2019-07-18 11:18:45 00:50:27    1
2019-07-18 11:18:46 00:07:20    1
2019-07-18 11:18:50 00:31:34    1
```

I find it's impossible to make a `PeriodIndex` with elements of `Peroid`(The used-walltime in each record are inconsistent).

I thought I can create a `PeriodIndex` with freq of `30 minutes`, then assign the number of cores of all records within a certian `Period` to the correspinding `Period`. But I can't figure out how to do this.

What I expected is :

```
    datetime cputime    ncores
    2019-07-18 11:0:00      5
    2019-07-18 11:30:00     4
    2019-07-18 12:00:00     3
    2019-07-18 12:30:00     2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
#convert to datetimes and timedeltas
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df['walltime'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['walltime'])

#create end time with flooring by 30min
df['end'] = df['datetime'].dt.floor('30min') + df['walltime']

#list by 30minutes period
zipped = zip(df['datetime'], df['end'], df['ncores'])
L = [(i, n) for s, e, n in zipped for i in pd.period_range(s, e, freq='30min')]

#DataFrame is aggregated by sum
df1 = (pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['datetime cputime', 'summed'])
        .groupby('datetime cputime', as_index=False)['summed']
        .sum())
print (df1)
   datetime cputime  summed
0  2019-07-18 11:00       5
1  2019-07-18 11:30       4
2  2019-07-18 12:00       3
3  2019-07-18 12:30       2
4  2019-07-18 13:00       2
```

Comment: Each record reprents a event at each time stamp, Some event may last for a long time which is dependent on `walltime` field.

Comment: What does `groupby('datetime cputime', as_index=False)['summed'].sum()` used for? It seems that `groupby('datetime cputime', as_index=False).sum()` works too.

Comment: @BAKEZQ - Difference is if not specify column after `groupby` it sum all columns. And because here only one numeric column it working same.